# ng-bind-html on a string containing angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular ng-bind-html to add a control to the current element. When I do this ,control gets added but any angular directive specified in the string is missing . For example

**Original string** : `'<a ng-click="hello()" style="color:#8FA2AF">Hello</a>';`
**Resulting control** : `<a style="color:#8FA2AF">Hello</a>`

Can anyone help?

**html**

```
<span >
      <p ng-bind-html="sample_text"> 
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
mymodule.controller('MyController',function MyController($scope) {
$scope.sample_text='<a ng-click="hello()" style="color:#8FA2AF">Hello</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use $sce.trustAsHtml() like this...

```
$scope.sample_text= $sce.trustAsHtml('`enter code here`<a ng-click="hello()" style="color:#8FA2AF">Hello</a>');
```

but this way you **cannot bind** scope variables (like your `hello()` function) to your html so best way is writing a directive...

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHOmnwfUTUo9YD7jG87K?p=preview) for both $sce and directive example...